# How do i append proper input as integers to an array in C, as long the user wishes to?

Tags: c, max

```
int main(){
    
    char answer; 
    int numbers[100];
    int i = 0;
    int size;
    int max = -9999;

    do{

        printf("Please enter an number: ");
        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
        printf("Would you like to keep adding numbers:(Y/N)");
        scanf("%c", &answer);
        scanf("%c");
        i++;

    }while(answer == 'Y');


    size = sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]);
    for(int j = 0; j<size; j++){
        if(numbers[j]>= max){
            max = numbers[j];
        }
    }

    printf("The max number is: %d", max);


return 0;

}
```

Hello beginner in C, here in my code i am trying to take an arbitrary amount of (the user enters Y if he/she wishes to enter another number.) input as integers  and add them to an array and find the maximum of the input using a for loop, however i am not getting the correct output. What could be the error in my code?

Comment: First off, don't **ever** use `scanf()` without checking the return value. Your `numbers[i]` might be uninitialized.

Comment: The FAQ: Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer). This is the moment to get used to debugging - had you examined what `scanf("%c", &answer);` input (numerically) you'd find out something.

Comment: When the user enters `17<enter>Y<enter>23...` the `<enter>` or `'\n'` is left in the buffer after the `scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);` reads the number. So, the `scanf("%c", &answer);` will read a `'\n'`, not the `'Y'`. You have to use `scanf(" %c", &answer);`, note the space before the `%c` to discard whitespaces.

Comment: You also need to check the compiler warnings, such as for `scanf("%c");` which is very likelt to crash the program.

Comment: You check the whole array, instead of just the values entered: `for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)`

Comment: @Mert Erdem, "take an arbitrary amount " --> Code has `int numbers[100];` limiting to 100.  Is that OK? If not, what limit?, 1000, million, billion, until all memory is used?

Comment: @Reinstate Monica Yes i know that it actually isn't arbitrary lets assume that the user wont enter past 100 numbers, the problem i have with my code is actually is related to the max output, here is a sample output:  Please enter an number: 5
Would you like to keep adding numbers:(Y/N)Y
Please enter an number: 9
Would you like to keep adding numbers:(Y/N)Y
Please enter an number: 14
Would you like to keep adding numbers:(Y/N)Y
Please enter an number: 26
Would you like to keep adding numbers:(Y/N)N
The max of all numbers entered is: 1980104705% why is the max so large? and not 26

Comment: Please read the comments carefully: they are explaining. Here is a repeat: You check the whole array, instead of just the values entered: `for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)`. The other elements you checked (from index `i` to `size-1`) were not initialised and have no values entered. They are indeterminate.

Comment: This little program will be much easier — both for you and the user — if you change it slightly.  One of the main problems you're having is reading the "would you like to keep adding?" answer, because `%c` is basically broken.  (Not your fault.)  But having to type Y or N is a nuisance for the user, too.  So tell the user, "Type as many numbers as you want, and the word "done" (or control-D, or control-Z, or anything non-numeric) when you're done."  Then just use `if(scanf("%d", &numbers[i]) != 1) break;` to exit the loop.  (One way or another you always want to check scanf's return value.)

Comment: The title of the question could be edited to "How do I use scanf() in a sane manner?", and the answer is "you don't".  As a beginner, you should avoid `scanf` completely.  When you are more comfortable with the language, your reasons for avoiding `scanf` will be slightly different, but you should continue avoiding it.

Answer (score 2):

Problems include:

**Reading a `'\n'` when a letter is expected**

`scanf("%c", &answer);` reads the character after the prior input of a number (example:<kbd>9</kbd>), which is likely the prior entry's `'\n'` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Use a space to consume leading white-space like `'\n'`, space, tab, ...

```
// scanf("%c", &answer);
scanf(" %c", &answer);
```

**Enable all warnings**

Invalid/unnecessary code `scanf("%c");` will raise a compiler warning with a well enabled compiler.

- Best advice in this answer: enable all compiler warnings to save time.

**Start at `INT_MIN`**

The maximum input may be less than -9999.
`INT_MIN` in `<limits.h>`

```
// int max = -9999;
int max = INT_MIN;
```

**Iterate to `i`**

Rather than iterate to 100, only need to iterate to `i`, the count of values entered.

```
// for(int j = 0; j<size; j++){
for(int j = 0; j<i; j++){
```

**Check return values**

`scanf()` returns a value indicated the number of successful conversions.  Use it to validated input successfully happened.

```
// scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
if (scanf("%d", &numbers[i]) != 1) {
  ; // Report error with TBD code.
}
```

**Do not loop too often**

```
// } while(answer == 'Y');
} while(answer == 'Y' && i < 100);
```

**There is no reason to save an array of values**

The maximum could be calculated as data is entered.

```
int max = INT_MIN;
do {
  int num;
  printf("Please enter an number: ");
  if (scanf("%d", number) != 1) {
    break;
  }
  if (num > max) {
    max = num;
  }
  printf("Would you like to keep adding numbers:(Y/N)");
  if (scanf(" %c", &answer) != 1) {
    break;
  }
} while (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');
printf("The max number is: %d", max);
```

---

**Future Improvements**

- Handle values outside `int` range.  Research `intmax_t`.
- Detect case of no valid input entered.  Research `fgets()`
- Detect non-valid `Y/N` input.  Research `fgets()`
- Recover, rather than quit loop with invalid input.